# Firemonkey MouseToCell equivalent

Tags: delphi, mouse, coordinates, firemonkey, tstringgrid

In Delphi VCL if I wanted to see which cell (column and row) of a TStringGrid my mouse was hovering over I'd use MouseToCell. This method is no longer in Delphi (XE2) for FireMonkey apps. Does anyone know how I can determine the cell my mouse is over? OnMouseMove has X & Y values but these are screen coordinates and not cell coordinates.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's actually a `MouseToCell` method in `TCustomGrid`, which the StringGrid descends, but it's private. Looking at its source, it makes use of `ColumnByPoint` and `RowByPoint` methods, which are fortunately public.

The 'column' one returns a `TColumn`, or nil if there's no column. The 'row' one returns a positive integer, or -1 when there's no row. Furthermore, the row one does not care the row count, it just accounts for row height and returns a row number based on this, even if there are no rows. Also, I should note that, behavior on grid header is buggy. Anyway, sample example could be like:

```
procedure TForm1.StringGrid1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Single);
var
  Col: TColumn;
  C, R: Integer;
begin
  Col := StringGrid1.ColumnByPoint(X, Y);
  if Assigned(Col) then
    C := Col.Index
  else
    C := -1;
  R := StringGrid1.RowByPoint(X, Y);

  Caption := Format('Col:%d Row:%d', [C, R]);
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

`TStringGrid` has a `ColumnByPoint` and `RowByPoint` method.

`ColumnByPoint` and `RowByPoint` go by the coordinates of the string grid. So, if you use the `OnMouseOver` of the string grid, the X and Y parameters will already be in the string grid's cooridnates.

Here's how to display the row and column (0 based) in the string grid's `OnMouseOver`:

```
var
  row: Integer;
  col: TColumn;
  colnum: Integer;
begin
  row := StringGrid1.RowByPoint(X, Y);
  col := StringGrid1.ColumnByPoint(X, Y);
  if Assigned(col) then
  begin
    colnum := col.Index;
  end
  else
  begin
    colnum := -1;
  end;
  Label1.Text := IntToStr(row) + ':' + IntToStr(colnum);
end;
```

Note that `-1` will be displayed when outside the bounds of the rows and columns.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, usually SO shows me when there's another answer while I'm writing mine. This time it didn't. I figured since I spent so much time on it, and it has some additional info, I'd just leave it.

Comment: @Marcus - Ok. Thanks for telling. I was a bit curious.. :)